# Laravel application with subdomains that can be linked to other domains via CNAME

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain

I'm trying to create an application architecture similar to that of Shopify's.

I am running this application from Forge and I've set up the necessary configuration for wildcard DNS to work.

At the moment people can sign up to my Laravel Spark app and then a subdomain will be created dynamically for them at:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{company}.app.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'SubdomainController@index');
});
```

So if they register an account and set the company name as `Company` then they will have a subdomain created at `company.app.com`. This subdomain returns a view with data related to their account (It pretty much returns a custom website for my user).

I'd like to give users the ability to mirror their site at `company.app.com` to their own domain address. I have tried setting up a mask within GoDaddy on a spare domain I have to test this however it doesn't seem to work :( I get this error in the console:

```
Refused to display 'http://company.app.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

So I'm guessing this is definitely not the right way to do it.

After this happened I looked at how other companies managed this and it looks like they create an A record and CNAME that points to the root of their app. [Shopify's guide](https://help.shopify.com/manual/domains/connecting-existing-domains/setting-up-your-domain#set-up-your-existing-domain-to-connect-to-shopify) explains that they add their IP as an A record and then the CNAME is set as the shops.myshopify.com domain.

So now I'm left wondering how I can point requests in the right direction when they land on my app. So for example if traffic hits `random.com` and it has an `A record` that is equal to my servers IP, plus a `CNAME` of `app.com`, then how do I handle the request and redirect it to the correct subdomain whilst keeping the user on their custom domain?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier than that. Your server is setting the X-Frame-Options header to SAMEORIGIN which means content from your site can only be rendered within a frame if that frame is on your domain.

You either get rid of that totally, so anyone can frame your content on any site, or you save your customers domains and do some sort of database lookup on the fly, or configure some sort of specific url for them to use for content linking which proxies to their directory on your server and has a part of the url which you can capture as a variable to use in your server config. Then you set your header to allow from their domain only.

So embed.myapp.com/example.com could serve the content from example.myapp.com and add the header

`X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have one other question, how does Shopify manage to do this without creating a Mask? Users seem to be able to change the A name to the server IP and then create a CNAME like so: https://youtu.be/Boqh4MItf60?t=5m29s

Comment: When I do the same thing and add my applications IP as the A record and the subdomain as the CNAME it displays the root domain of my application but not the subdomain :(

Comment: Here is an example (obviously the values are fake). https://image.ibb.co/iA2Qcn/Screen_Shot_2018_03_03_at_17_45_28.png

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood what you are trying to do. My solution will be easier for non tech savvy customers of yours, the video you link works the other way around, so the owner of example.com has to create an A record for myapp.example.com and point it at example.myapp.com

Comment: In other words you don't point your subdomain at them, they point theirs at you.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to explain. I have set up a test domain that mimics a customer. So I'm trying to link it up as a customer from a secondary domain to my app.

Comment: enter an A record for the subdomain and point it at your app server ip address

Comment: I've done that, my test domain does link to my app however it isn't linking to my subdomain on my app. It should as I have created a CNAME that links to the company.app.com subdomain.

Comment: You need to handle that at a server level, all DNS records do is map domains to IP addresses. All your requests will come to the same IP, your server needs to inspect the request and serve the correct content accordingly

Comment: So why does Shopify provide that a user adds a CNAME that equals their store on a subdomain? What does that achieve?

Comment: Also how would you handle the request if you don't know where the traffic is coming from? Sorry knew to all of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166162/discussion-between-miknik-and-nick-maddren).