# Multi-tenant rails application with a domain/subdomain architecture like Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi-tenant rails application, similar to Shopify. Whenever a customer registers an `Account`, they will have a subdomain created at `customer.myapp.com`. This subdomain returns a view with data related to their account (including a /admin area).

Now in some cases, customers would like to use their own custom domain, instead of the subdomain created for them. How do I need to adjust my rails routes and controllers to return a view with data related to the customers account, based on not just the subdomain but on either the custom domain OR the subdomain?

This is how I've set up my `config/routes.rb` for handling subdomains:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  constraints(SubdomainRequired) do
    scope module: :accounts do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

With `app/constraints/subdomain_required.rb` looking like this:

```
# app/constraints/subdomain_required.rb
class SubdomainRequired
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
  end
end
```

And finally my `app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb` setting the current account, based on the requests subdomain:

```
# app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb
module Accounts
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_current_account
    ...
    def set_current_account
      if request.subdomain.present?
        @current_account = Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
        render_404 if !@current_account
      end
    end

    def render_404
      render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", status: 404
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

For the DNS setup I followed the approach of companies like Shopify. It looks like they have their customers create an A record that points to the primary IP address of their app. And they have them create a CNAME for the "www" subdomain, which points to a subdomain (`sites.myapp.com`), set up as a CNAME for the apps subdomain (in my case managed by DigitalOcean's app platform).

IF the DNS Settings work as intended, I'm left wondering how I can point requests in the right direction when the customer lands on my app. So for example if traffic hits `customer.com` and it has an A record pointing to my servers primary IP, plus a CNAME for `sites.myapp.com`, how do I handle the request and redirect it to the correct subdomain whilst keeping the user on their custom domain?

These are the resources I've checked so far:

- [Laravel application with subdomains that can be linked to other domains via CNAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086741/laravel-application-with-subdomains-that-can-be-linked-to-other-domains-via-cnam)
- [multi tenant with custom domain on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821755/multi-tenant-with-custom-domain-on-rails)
- [Multi-tenant dynamic multiple domains with SSL pointing to single Host/CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931882/multi-tenant-dynamic-multiple-domains-with-ssl-pointing-to-single-host-cdn)
- https://answers.netlify.com/t/subdomain-and-custom-domain-based-multi-tenant-application/30482/2
- https://www.indiehackers.com/post/how-do-i-setup-a-domain-to-subdomain-architecture-like-shopify-70413820da
- https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/connecting-domains#set-up-your-existing-domain-to-connect-to-shopify

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately I cannot help you but I think your question is well asked and properly formatted (which is not the case for most new members). Keep on!

Comment: Thanks @Hecke29 for welcoming me. I'm glad that my question is well asked and properly formatted. In fact I figured out most of it myself in the meantime and I'm going to update it as soon as I'm done testing my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so this is what I came up with in the meantime.

First of all I left my `config/routes.rb` as described above. Everything seemed to be working as intended there.

Then I adjusted `app/constraints/subdomain_required.rb` to not only check for the subdomain but also the domain part of the request:

```
# app/constraints/subdomain_required.rb
class SubdomainRequired
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www" || 
      request.domain.present? && request.domain != ENV["APP_DOMAIN"]
  end
end
```

And last but not least I changed the `set_current_account` method in `app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb` to this monster of an if statement:

```
# app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb
module Accounts
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_current_account
    ...
    def set_current_account
      @current_account = if request.domain.present? && request.domain != ENV["APP_DOMAIN"]
                           # Do custom domain stuff
                           if request.subdomain == "www" || !request.subdomain.present?
                             # Set current account by custom domain, e.g. custom.com
                             Account.find_by(domain: request.domain)
                           else
                             # Set current account by custom subdomain, e.g. site.custom.com
                             Account.find_by(domain: "#{request.subdomain + "." + request.domain}")
                           end
                         elsif request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
                           # Set current account by subdomain, e.g. site.myapp.com
                           Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
                         end
      render_404 unless @current_account
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

As of now I'm still testing my solution. Might need some more tweaking and definitely a little bit of refactoring but it seems to be working.

Another (unexpected) problem that I had to solve was the whole DNS setup. Similar to heroku, DigitalOcean's app platform doesn't support static IP addresses and therefore a client wouldn't be able to just create an A record, pointing to my app's IP address, since it could change at any time.

For now I've set up a forwarding proxy (is this how you call it?) with NGINX, based on the following example for heroku:
https://help.heroku.com/YTWRHLVH/how-do-i-make-my-nginx-proxy-connect-to-a-heroku-app-behind-heroku-ssl

Hope that helps anybody out there, looking for a similar solution.

Let me know if I need to elaborate.